# How to use Modules in Angular 7 to conditionally bind a class or attribute value in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Using ngFor to loop through an array of items, i want items with an EVEN index to have a different background color from items with an ODD index. i was able to achieve this in VueJs using the code below:

I have tried the Angular Code below, No Success:

```
 <ion-col  *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(50); let i = index" >

               <ion-card [attr.color]="{'secondary': i % 2, 'primary': !(i % 2)}">

</ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

VueJs Code: this code works for me in VueJs but i need to achieve this same logic in Angular 7

```
<div v-for="(itemforsale, index) in filteredListMainitemsforsale">

<div :class="{'box bg-success text-center': index % 2, 'box bg-info text-center': !(index % 2)}" >


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: just use css even and odd property

Comment: you can use in the *ngFor "let event=even" see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf and ngClass `[ngClass]="{even? 'text-center box bg-success':'text-center bg-info'}"` or `[ngClass]="{'text-center box bg-success':even,'text-center bg-info'}:!even"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

```
<ion-col  *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(50); let i = index" >
     <ion-card [ngStyle]="{'color': i % 2 == 0 ? 'secondary' : 'primary'}">
     </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-col  *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(50); let i = index" >
  <ion-card [style.color]="i % 2 === 0 ? 'secondary' : 'primary'">

  </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<ion-card [style.color]="i % 2?'secondary': 'primary'">
```

For background color:

```
 <ion-card [style.background-color]="i % 2?'secondary': 'primary'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fia7hx

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; index as i">
    <p  [ngClass]="{greyClass: i%2 === 0}">
      {{item}}
    </p>
</div>

.greyClass {
    background-color: grey;
}
```